# how can i add responsiveness to an abstract div

Tags: html, css, responsive

```
.cover{
background-color: #212129;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:50%;}

.profile{
width:120px;
height:120px;
position:absolute;
bottom:-60px;
left:64px;
background-color: black;}

header img{
width:100%;
height:100%;}

<header class="heading">        
    <div class="cover"><!--Main banner-->
        <img src="img/cover.jpg" alt="cover">

        <div class="profile">
            <img class="img img-thumbnail" src="img/dp.jpg" alt="profile">
        </div>
    </div>  
</header
```

when i change the size of screen nothing happens with profile image. It didn't change its size. I want to make it responsive. I tried by added img and img-thumbnail classes but all in vain. please help me to add responsiveness in this abstract div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you intend with responsive?
Your `.profile` container has both height and width set with an absolute unit (pixels) and the image inside .profile will always be large and tall 100% of it, so it is normal it does not change.

You should use percentage sizes also for that container, or some media queries to define different sizes for different viewports.

Answer (score 0):

Add img-responsive Class To Your Image

```
<img class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="img/dp.jpg" alt="profile">
.profile{
width:100%;
height:120px;
position:absolute;
bottom:-60px;
left:64px;
background-color: black;}
```

Comment: Add Width:100%; in your Profile Class Don't  Give Fixed Width To That

Comment: Remove width:120px; In Profile Class And Add width:100%; Then It Will Works Fine

Comment: if i add 100% width it occupies the whole page's width and become creepy

Comment: Send Me Your Site Screen Shot

Comment: then you can use bootstrap grids